# Unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Unknown Module

Tags: c#, unhandled-exception

For .NET I normally code in VB, but I'm having to work on a project in C#, and bumped into this weird issue.

I have 3 classes (`Form1`, and 2 added classes that call controls and methods on `Form1`).

To make life easier, in `Program.cs` I added:

`public static Form1 form1 = new Form1(); // Place this var out of the constructor Application.Run(form1);`

and then just call the `Form1` stuff with something like:

`Program.form1.ResetForm();`

Here's where it gets weird though. I can use that exact line above on one class (say, `clsFoo.cls`) and it works fine, but, that exact same line (and any others that use `Program.form1.`) on `clsBar.cls` create the error in the title.

When running the program and it hits a line in `clsBar.cls` that uses that, I get this:

[image: screenshot]

And the error shown in the output:

> Exception thrown: 'System.NullReferenceException' in YourProgram.exe
>   An unhandled exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in Unknown Module.
>   The type initializer for 'Your.Program' threw an exception.

From all that I can tell, I'm using the same exact namespaces, class names, Usings, etc. I've also set any relative controls on `Form1`'s Modifiers to `Public`.

Not being super experienced w/C#, I'm kinda stuck on this one. Anyone know what's up?

Comment: Please read how to and [edit] your post to include a [mcve].

Comment: assembly load failure during static variable initialization would throw that. Make sure u have all assemblies compiled for the same CPU architecture.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, without posting the entire 3 classes, I gave all code and information relevant to the respective problem....

Comment: That would be true if I was able to reproduce the problem with the code in the question, and that's not the case. You don't need to post the 3 classes entirely, just what's relevant

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto, I'm all ears then; give me a direct example of the exact portion of code you're looking for, that isn't a part of my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that the code in that class was being called before the code initializing `Form1` in `Program.cs` was called. Weird.